# Delegate methods not fired

Tags: cocoa-touch, delegates

Any problems I can think of is checked out, but still the delegate methods won't fire. I have declared a protocol called SocketDelegate in `Socket.h`:

```
@protocol SocketDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)socket:(Socket *)socket handleNewConnection:(NSString *)test;
- (void)socket:(Socket *)socket didSend:(BOOL)didSend;
- (void)socket:(Socket *)socket didReceive:(BOOL)didReceive;
@end

@interface Socket : NSObject {
    id<SocketDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<SocketDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Now, in `Socket.m`, the delegate is notified with success/error of a sent/received file:

```
@implementation Socket

/* I checked: both of these methods are called */

- (void)stopSendWithStatus:(NSString *)statusString {
    [self.delegate socket:self didSend:isSent];
}

- (void)stopReceiveWithStatus:(NSString *)statusString {
    [self.delegate socket:self didReceive:isReceived];
}

@end
```

`ViewController.h` conforms to the delegate:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SocketDelegate>
```

and in `ViewController.m`, I set the delegate through a `NetController` class that link Socket and ViewController together. and I implement the delegate methods:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    /* I checked: this method is called */
    /* Both 'netController' and 'socket' are initialized correctly
    netController = [[NetController alloc] init];
    [[netController socket] setDelegate:self];  
}

@end

@implementation ViewController (SocketDelegate)

- (void)socket:(Socket *)socket didSend:(BOOL)didSend {
    NSLog(@"didSend %@", didSend);        // Nothing happens...
}

- (void)socket:(Socket *)socket didReceive:(BOOL)didReceive {
    NSLog(@"didReceive %@", didReceive);  // Nothing happens...
}

@end
```

Also, I have tried to set the delegate other places than viewDidLoad inside ViewController.m, but it have no effect. Ofcourse I have no compiler errors, and no runtime errors... What is going wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `-viewDidLoad` is called? Your `ViewController` class does not inherit from anything, I think you want to do:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SocketDelegate>
```

Make sure `-viewDidLoad` is called, if it's not, it probably hasn't been hooked up in the NIB file or created programmatically. Next step, make sure the socket functions are trying to call the delegate functions. Also, the `Socket` class doesn't inherit from anything either, I don't know how you construct your socket inside netController, but I had to change to

```
@interface Socket : NSObject
```

in order to be able to construct an object. Make sure that the socket object inside netController is properly constructed. Remember that if they are nil, no warnings will be given when you try to send messages to them.

Fixing all of those things, this worked for me.

Comment: I tried to post as short as possible, but I have obviously left out a lot of information here! I feel guilty of wasting your time here, sorry! Actually, I have checked everything you mentioned too many times but I can't figure out where's the error. I can't find any objects not initialized, but I guess this is probably the most obvious place to look for errors. Do you agree, or can you think of something else going on here? I'm pretty sure the implementation of the delegate and the use of it is set up correctly...

Comment: You have probably done this already, but set a breakpoint in `-stopSendWithStatus` and check `self.delegate` again, then do a step through to see exactly what is happening. If the delegate is not nil, then it will either go into the function or complain.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the socket itself (which is part of the NetController object) is not initialized correctly, or released before firing the delegate call. How do you initialize the socket that's part of the NetController object?

Comment: The socket object is initialized when I initialize the netController object inside ViewController class, viewDidLoad method. I've checked it and they seem ok...